# Evaluating / ranking in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ranking

I have Pandas DataFrame where I imported Excel spreadsheet which contains couple of hundreds rows. Each row is a company name with some fundamental data as ratios etc. in each column.

```
Symbol  Name  P/BV  PE     NCB

A       AGT   4.382 42.59  0.0145

AAAP    AdvAc 6.91  NaN    -0.0003

AAME    AtlAm 0.6205 29.55 0.0089

AAN     Aaron 2.093 23.89  0.0213
```

etc. There is more columns and more rows, but I think this is enough to illustrate the data. Sometimes there is no value for a ratio, so automatically there was filled NaN value.

What I would like to do is to evaluate each company:

- each column (P/BV for example) is a universe that contains values from lowest to the highest - creating a scope of 100 %. Each company will be evaluated in new column: I want to assign percentile ranking for each company 1 to 100. If company has P/BV ratio that is in lowest 1% of the universe, it receives rank 100 (as lowest is the best here). The highest ratio receives rank 1.
- if a value is missing - there is NaN - assign rank 50
- I need to evaluate each column like that, so I need to create new column for each ratio column and fill it with the ranking values.
- some ratios are best when it's value is highest, like the column NCB.

Later on I will add all the rank values for each company in the final column, which I can manage. I just cannot make this ranking to work. Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also, for those who do not know what these ratios mean, it would be best to supply us with a desired outcome so we know what you want to do

Comment: @MattR Well, I stopped at that point, as I realised my knowledge of Pandas is not enough to make that ranking. Generally, let's say for the column P/BV there is 400 rows, and values are for example from 0.00 to 100.00. Then values from 0.00 to 1.00 are in first 1 %, and all the companies which have that value in P/BV column would be assigned rank 100. Values from 1.01 to 2.00 are in 2 % and the companies with values in this scope would be ranked with 99. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using similar data.  In this example:

- Low P/B & PE receives high rank (inverse rank)
- Missing value receives 50% (50th percentile)
- High MCV receives high rank (direct rank)

Sample DataFrame:

```
  Symbol     P_BV     PE      NCB
0      A -0.59587  42.50 -1.42680
1      B  0.09875    NaN -0.82033
2      C  0.10987  29.55  0.73841
3      D  3.03278  23.89 -0.31283
4      E  0.70129  10.00 -1.00830
```

Now use [`DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with the parameter `pct=True`.  The slighly time-consuming part is you'll need to apply it separately for different columns because you want to rank some ascending and some descending.

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df.loc[:, ['P_BV', 'PE']] = (df[['P_BV', 'PE']]
                                     .rank(pct=True, ascending=False) * 100)
new_df.loc[:, 'NCB'] = df['NCB'].rank(pct=True) * 100  # ascending=True
```

Lastly, fill `NaN` values with 50:

```
new_df.fillna(value=50., inplace=True)
```

Your result looks like this:

```
  Symbol   P_BV     PE    NCB
0      A  100.0   25.0   20.0
1      B   80.0   50.0   60.0
2      C   60.0   50.0  100.0
3      D   20.0   75.0   80.0
4      E   40.0  100.0   40.0
```

Combined code you'll need:

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df.loc[:, ['P_BV', 'PE']] = (df[['P_BV', 'PE']]
                                     .rank(pct=True, ascending=False) * 100)
new_df.loc[:, 'NCB'] = df['NCB'].rank(pct=True) * 100  # ascending=True
new_df.fillna(value=50., inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @Brad First part works perfectly for me, but the second part where ascending=True does not work. It gives an error, but I used my Excel file to load data into Pandas DataFrame: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
SystemError: <cyfunction Infinity.<lambda> at 0x10a86edf0> returned a result with an error set

Comment: @MichalŠplho What does `df.NCB.dtype` give you?  Are there any strings in the column or very large/very small numbers?  Try `new_df.loc[:, 'NCB'] = pd.to_numeric(df['NCB']).rank(pct=True) * 100`.

Comment: @BradSolomonI had couple of strings in that column, like: -1.85K, (around 5 among 4650), and this caused the error message. Your last code helped me to detect the position of the string, it always displayed error but  displayed the position of the string in the column. I corrected the data and now you original code works like swiss watch :-) Thank you very much :-)